# Getting Autotest to Work with Growl on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, autotest, growl

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.7 on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

I have had the most terrible time getting growl to display autotest notifications.  I have autotest installed and working perfectly.

Every time I make a change to a file, the tests are run without a problem.  Growl simply refuses to work.  In my Growl preferences panel I can see that autotest is added to the list of applications and enabled and Growl is on and running.  Here's what my gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'annotate-models'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem "ZenTest"
  gem "autotest-rails-pure"
  gem "autotest-growl"
  gem "autotest-fsevent"
end
```

And here's my .autotest file:

```
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/fsevent'
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work. I tried:

- following the first two pages of guides on Google for autotest and OS X.
- deleting my gemset in RVM and reinstalling.
- running `bundle install` dozens of times.
- installing the `test_notifier` gem.

None of these steps seemed to work.  I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.  It's been a frustrating two days trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Guard-RSpec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) to run your specs. It's easy to install, and it works with Growl. Be sure to look at the base [Guard gem](https://github.com/guard/guard). I've switched over from Autotest over a month ago and have been happy. Here's the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard) about Guard.

Comment: This looks really nice, and it seems to work well.  However, Growl still isn't displaying notifications.  The first time I ran it, it told me to install the growl gem, which I did, but I'm still not seeing anything.

Comment: I cleared my Growl installation and started a new project, which I then copied my files into.  I then installed this gem again and it worked.  I don't know if what I did actually solved the problem or not, but it's working now, so I'm happy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting `gem 'autotest-growl'` in your development group? I've always put it there and have had no problems; I've just assumed it's the same reason that you have `gem 'rspec-rails'` in your development group.

Comment: Is it picking up your `.autotest` file at all? I'm curious if you put something ridiculous in there if it would fail...

Comment: I tried to add some gibberish to my .autotest file, and it caught it.